# In Xcode, is there a way to set up a table which is not for UI but like an 'engine' for processing data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, spreadsheet

I'm wondering if there is some sort of way to set up something similar to a spreadsheet in Xcode. I'm trying to create a 'tapping game' or a 'clicker game' and storing so many variables in regular coding would be really tough.

Having this 'table' would enable me to keep track of multipliers and upgrade levels instead of clogging my coding with it.

Preferably, I could then just tell my code what to pull and what to look for off of the table. The table would be an 'engine' of sorts and it would not be UI. The table would do all of the work behind scenes, then show it through UI based on labels and buttons.

Comment: Short answer - a `UITableView` is a UI representation of data. So you are essentially asking: "Can I use a UI element that represents my data for use with other UI elements." My question to you is: why not just use your data directly? Instead of asking about using a table in the background, try describing exactly what you want to do, and think about how to set up your data (arrays? sets? dictionaries?) to accomplish that.

Comment: Not exactly - I don't need a UITableView, unless it can work like I want it to. I don't honestly mind what I use as long as it's hidden, and acts similar to a spreadsheet. The reason I'm not using my data directly is simply because there are too many equations because there are so many upgrades and so many objects being upgraded.

Comment: Are you actually trying to create a spreadsheet app / component?

Comment: No... what I'm asking might simply be impossible.

Comment: OK - as I said... *"try describing exactly what you want to do"*. What you are asking may be impossible, but you haven't asked it yet, so we have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As traxido is saying, without more details we can't point you to a concrete example/solution. Base on the title the answer is yes. It's not a ui component though. It doesn't even need to be one. 
What you want is a data structure to hold your data in a way that's convenient to access (save and retrieve).  You could create a class which is a composite of other data structures like arrays and dictionaries and possibly other data structures. You might end up having many questions before you're through. 
So: the answer is yes. Try it yourself and ask new questions if you get stuck. 
Provide the code and error messages and I bet you quickly get answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Create a shared or singleton instance and retain all the data in instances of it. 
(or) create a custom data structure and overide set or get methods to autoprocess the exiting data everytime you add or delete data element

Ex: If you want to maintain an array thats is always sorted. MySortedArray is the custom structure that inherits NSMutableArray and maintain a protected NSMutableArray instance. Overide addObject method to ensure sorting it whenever a new object is added.